# Javascript Order Of Execution Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, execution

I'm having an issue with Javascript executing things in an order that doesn't make sense to me.

What is happening is the following

```
var bValid = false;
alert(bValid + " 1");
if(validateForm() == TRUE)
{
    $.get("submit_manageUsers.php",  
        {action: sendAct, userID: userID},  
        function(responseText)
        {  
            if(responseText == "GOOD")
            {
                alert("Update Successful");
                bValid = true;
                alert(bValid + " 2");
            }
            else
            {
                alert(responseText + "\n Update Unsuccessful");
                bValid = false;
            }
        },  
        "html"  
    );     
    bvalid = true;
    alert(bValid + " 3");
}
alert(bValid + " 4");
if(bValid == true)
{
    //do something
}
alert(bValid + " 5");
```

EDIT: added a bit more of what is actually happening in case it helps, probably will knowing how I do things!

The output from the above code looks like this:

false 1

false 2

false 4

false 5

true 3.

The problem here is that the `if(bValid == true)` is being executed before the `if(validateForm() == TRUE)` so this means bValid is always false.

Why is that part of the code executing before the other part?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: TRUE is what the function validateForm() should return to set the bValid variable to TRUE as well.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ which produces this output. If `TRUE` is not defined, the code will just fail and does not produce any further output. If it is defined, the output will be different. From my point of view, the order of output is impossible.

Comment: will jsfiddle allow for jQuery?

Comment: Oh.......the `alert(bValid + " 2")` is in your ajax callback function!!!!

Comment: @Adam: You could just follow the link and have a look ;) But now that you added more information, the problem is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. validateForm（） returns a bool right?  So its either true or false.  TRUE is **not** the same as true.

```
if (validateForm（） == true) { // do something. }
```

I would even go one step further and use strict equals:

```
if (validateForm（） === true) { // do something. }
```

Also, bvalid is **not** the same as bValid.

In the future I would suggest utilizing one of the numerous javascript tools out there to help find syntax errors (such as jsfiddle, jslint, jsbin, etc.).  We all make mistakes, and sometimes these little simple details cause big headaches.  There is not a compiler crutch (like I use everyday with C#) for javascript although YUI and Google have syntax checking tools to help.

Google - http://code.google.com/closure/

Yahoo! - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/

After more information was provided in the original question -

You are making an **asynchronous** call to your PHP page that may take 1 second or 30 seconds.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

JQuery ajax (which powers the .get function) is **asynchronous** by default.  However, you can override this and make synchronous.

Comment: i wish this was a syntax error, but i just rushed when typing the question out, all variables are spelled the same in the real code, i think this has to do with the jQuery .get and how that runs, but not entirely sure how that works!

Comment: I want to see that validateForm() function.

Comment: You are making an asynchronous call to your PHP page that may take 1 second or 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify true or false on those conditions. Try something like this and see if it resolves your issue:

```
var bValid = false; 
alert(bValid + " 1"); 

if (validateForm()) { 
    bvalid = true; 
    alert(bValid + " 2"); 
} 

alert(bValid + " 3"); 
if (bValid) {
    //do something 
} 

alert(bValid + " 4");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var bValid = false;
alert(bValid + " 1");

if(validateForm() == TRUE){
    bvalid = true;
    alert(bValid + " 2");
}
alert(bValid + " 3");

setTimeout(function() { // Continue le script après l'insertion du html
    if(bValid == true){
        //do something
    }
    alert(bValid + " 4");
}, 0);
```

This way, the first part of your script should be done before it start the second validation.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` is asynchronous. This means you send the message, you hang up the phone, and you wait for jQuery to call you back when it's done with `submit_manageUsers.php`. Step 3 and Step 4 are done after you hang up the phone, but step 2 only happens after the callback is called, which may be a while. That is why your messages are out of order.

```
$.get(url, data, function(response) { 
    if (response == 'GOOD') {
       alert('success!');
       DoSomethingMeaninfulHere();
    } else {
       alert(response + "\n Update Unsuccessful");
    }
});
```

you have to put the call to

```
// DoSomethingMeaningfulHere
alert(bValid + " 4");
if(bValid == true)
{
    //do something
}
alert(bValid + " 5");
```

inside of the callback for it to be executed at the correct time (which is after the AJAX request completes)